# When we make hashcode of 2 objects to point to one address,why it is temporary?

Tags: java, hashcode

Here `Equals_to_operator` is a Class and have a  parameterized constructor               `public Equals_to_operator(int dd, int mm, int yy)`. 
`e` and `f` are two object which calls the parameterized constructor with same argument.
I have overriden the `hashCode` and made both the hashCode of objects same.
Eventhough making the hashcode same(memory location of object same) it gives Output:not equals

I want to perform same by making hashcode same,where i am going wrong?

```
   public class Equals_to_operator {
    private int dd,mm,yy;

    public Equals_to_operator(int dd, int mm, int yy) {

        this.dd = dd;
        this.mm = mm;
        this.yy = yy;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Equals_to_operator [dd=" + dd + ", mm=" + mm + ", yy=" + yy + "]";
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Equals_to_operator e=new Equals_to_operator(7, 1, 2016);
        System.out.println(e+"\n"+e.hashCode());
        Equals_to_operator f=new Equals_to_operator(7, 1, 2016);
        System.out.println(f+"\n"+f.hashCode());
        if (e==f)
            System.out.println("equals");
        else
            System.out.println("not equals");
    }
```

Comment: You're creating two different objects so they won't be the same with the == operator. Changing the result from the hashCode method has no impact on the "memory location" of an object.

Comment: when we make hashCode of two object same,wont both object point to same memory location?

Comment: The return value of hashCode() is not the memory address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eventhough making the hashcode same(memory location of object same) it gives Output:not equals

Having same hashcode doesn't mean that objects are equal.

`memory location of object same` ... That's not what hashcode does. where from did you get that?

> if (e==f)

It means that condition will be true iff both `e` and `f` are pointing to same object.

Based on your `equals` method, both the objects pointed by `e` and `f` are equal but `==` but checks reference equality not the contents.

Comment: if you write `e = f;`

Comment: @RushabhOswal Using `e = f` makes your code "forget" the old `f` altogether, because it becomes eligible for garbage collection. In any event, neither `hashCode` nor `equals` plays into it.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have a fundamental misunderstanding over the way `equals` and `hashCode` interact. These two methods work in collaboration, not as substitutes for one another. Moreover, you seem to misunderstand the way these two methods interact with operator `==`: they don't; operator `==` checks object identity, so in your program it will return `false` even if you properly override `hashCode` and `equals`.

You must always override both these methods in pairs, and call `equals` to check equality.

Returning the same hash code tells hash-based containers that your objects *may be* equal, thus triggering an additional call to `equals`; returning different hash codes allows hash containers to skip the call to `equals`.

**Required reading:** documentation for [`hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) and [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 1):

```
== // checks equality in terms of memory address
something.equals(somethingElse) // enforces your own terms of what "equals" is if. If you wish to do this, override "equals()"
hashCode() // used when you're trying to use a collection such as a hashmap to map a key object to a value
```

You probably should look into the documentation for these items, but the difference between == and .equals() is something that you really need to understand.

EDIT: a side-note: If when you're looking more into hashCode() you read somewhere that the toString() representation of an Object by default (no overridden toString()) is a form of the memory address, that's a common misconception. It's actually the hashCode--but I digress.

Comment: It's not a misconception, the default implementation of Object.hashCode does use the memory address as the basis to form the hashCode. But it doesn't work the other way around, changing the hashCode doesn't affect the memory address. See Object.hashCode Javadoc: As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects. (This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)